# Element not found with webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am automating a android app with Appium using Java. My scenario is, I need to click either button 1 or button 2, whichever is present

> Appium error log:[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug]
>   Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
>   [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding
>   '//android.widget.ImageButton[@resource-id='net.ilius.android.meetic:id/profileMailPremiumButton']'
>   using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false

```
if (driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@resource-id='net.ilius.android.meetic:id/profileMailPremiumButton']")
        .isDisplayed()) {
     driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@resource-id='net.ilius.android.meetic:id/profileMailPremiumButton']")
        .click();
} else {
    driver.findElementById("net.ilius.android.meetic:id/profileMailButton").click();
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Especially include the complete error message and the relevant part of the HTML.

Comment: @sandy : use findElements with isEmpty method to check whether element  exists or not

Comment: Doesn't both the _Locator Strategy_ `findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@resource-id='net.ilius.android.meetic:id/profileMailPremiumButton']")` and `findElementById("net.ilius.android.meetic:id/profileMailPremiumButton")` refer to the same element?

Comment: @DebanjanB edited. sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

If you use the **isDisplayed()** and element is not present on the UI **it will throw the exception - element not found**.

So instead of that first check whether that element is exist or not by using the findElements  : **`driver.findElements(selector).isEmpty()`**

if it is empty it means element is not available now you can go to the else block

**Use this piece of code :** 
`

```
if (!driver.findElements(By.xPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@resource-id='button1']")).isEmpty()) {
     driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@resource-id='button1']").click();
} else {
    driver.findElementById("button2").click();
}`
```

Comment: I get the error:
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.

Comment: Yes. Infact i need to click anyone button whichever is present. The logic is only one button will be present.

Comment: It still searches for the "button1".

Comment: try this --------

if (!driver.findElements(By.xPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@resource-id='button1']")).isEmpty()) {
  if(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@resource-id='button1']").isDisplayed())   driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@resource-id='button1']").click();
} else {
    driver.findElementById("button2").click();
}`

Comment: Its the same code as you mentioned above right? i tried it and when executing, it searches for the button 1 when button 2 is only present in the application.

Comment: i have added one condition in first if block copy and try it

Comment: I did. And it still searches for the button 1 whereas button2 is present in the application.

Comment: I think the xpath may be incorrect.  They probably both have the same resource-id BUT have difference index numbers.  A screenshot of the uiautomator might help here.